# Trouble Booting Ubuntu After Install

Tags: installation, boot

I have been having trouble installing Ubuntu/Mint on a Gateway All-In-One computer.
I have set the boot order.  If I let the computer boot up, it gives me the error message, "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key".  (This is while I have a USB Flash Drive with an operating system plugged in.)

If I press F12 when I get the message "Press F12 display boot menu", I get the options

```
UEFI: WDC WD5000AAKX-001CA0
UEFI: KingstonDT 101 G2 1.00 (Flash Drive)
PO: WDC WD5000AAKX-001CAO
KingstonDT 101 G2 1.00 (Same Flash Drive).
```

If I select `UEFI: WDC WD5000AAKX-001CA0` or `PO: WDC WD5000AAKX-001CAO`, I get the error message, "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key".

If I select `UEFI: KingstonDT 101 G2 1.00`, I get the GNU GRUB version 2.00-13ubuntu3 menu.

If I select `KingstonDT 101 G2 1.00`, I get the standard boot up.

I have run through the install, replacing the previous operating system.  I have done this with both, Linux Mint 15 and Ubuntu 13.10.  Everything installs fine, but when it asks you to restart the computer, I select restart now.

If I let the computer boot up on it's own I get the same "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key" error.  If I open up the boot menu and try them all the only one's to work are `UEFI: KingstonDT 101 G2 1.00 (Flash Drive)` and `KingstonDT 101 G2 1.00 (Same Flash Drive)`.  If I run through the install again, I am given the option to replace the operating system I just tried to install.

I know that there is nothing wrong with the hard disk, install file, or flash drive.  If I try and boot from a disk, it does not find it, even though I have it set to the top of the boot order.

Sorry for the very wordy post, but I felt the need to provide as much information as possible.  I have tried all of the basic remedies and would appreciate some enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure GRUB is installed on your primary hard drive?

If not I would try to boot any of your systems and try to install GRUB on your primary hard drive.You can google on how to do that.

Comment: I have no working operating system on the computer and wasn't able to find any tutorials on what to do without having an operating system running.